# Issue with pasting HTML table through Excel VBA, Error handling doesn't seem to work

Tags: excel, vba

I have a client who is reporting that he gets an error on this line when running the macro for updating currency exchange rates:
`ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True`

The PasteSpecial method fails.

The main issue is that I cannot even replicate the error. With internet connection the macro works for me and if I turn my connection off, the macro pastes a message instead of giving me the same error. I never even get to the error handling message I created. When I try to troubleshoot on call with the client the macro works.

Here is an extract from the code where the error is:

```
    shtBNR.Activate
    shtBNR.Range("B3").Select
    shtBNR.Range("B:B").NumberFormat = "@"
    
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .Navigate "https://www.bnr.ro/StatisticsReportHTML.aspx?icid=800&table=668&column=&startDate=1-1-" & Year(Now) - 1 & " &stopDate=" & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    End With
  
    
RetryCount = 0
    
RetryCopy:
    
    RetryCount = RetryCount + 1
    
    If RetryCount = 5 Then
        
        MsgBox "Connection error! FX cannot be updated!"
        IE.Quit
        IE.Quit
        Exit Sub
        
    End If
    
    IE.ExecWB 17, 0
    IE.ExecWB 12, 2
    
    
    On Error GoTo RetryCopy
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    IE.Quit
    IE.Quit
```

I appreciate any clue or suggestions at this point.

Comment: What error does client get? Best option would be you connecting on remote to client computer, and see when this error arises and debug it.

Comment: The PasteSpecial method fails. I tried troubleshooting remote and it works, it only happens occasionally.